# "Could not find libmad on your system:" for installing VLC on Scientific Linux?

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux, vlc

I am trying to download VLC for use on my Scientific Linux. After going to the vlc-2.0.6 folder, I ran "./configure" and got error messages

```
configure: error: Could not find libmad on your system: you may get it from http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/. Alternatively you can use     --disable-mad to disable the mad plugin.
```

I went to that link and downloaded madplay, libmad, libid3tag, and was able to configure all of them with no problems. However, when I go back to the vlc folder and run "./configure", I still get the same error.

I heard one solution may be to use sudo-apt. But when I try that I get the error

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

apt-get is for debian-based distros, yours is based on red hat and has yum for software management. you should just do `sudo yum install vlc` and it will download and install vlc and all of its dependency's for you.

P.S.: read trough [this faq](http://www.fedorafaq.org/) for understending how to work with your linux distro, it is for Fedora users, but most of it should be the same for SL

Comment: when I tried that, I got the message saying "Sorry, user csx is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/yum install vlc' as root"

Comment: Than you did not do the sudo part.

Comment: Could you please mark this as answered?